# Can't delete photo, right clicking doesn't bring up trash can

Tags: photos, macos, contextual-menu

I'm trying to delete a photo but it won't bring up any trash icons I've read about when right clicked.
I tried dragging it to trash on the Dock and there are now multiple copies of the photo in the trash but it is still in my photos.

Comment: Where are you trying to delete the image from?

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut to delete files in Finder is usually <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

And in other apps it is usually just <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Dragging a picture out of Photos will generate a copy of that picture wherever you drag it - including in the Trash.

To completely delete a picture from photos, select it in the All Photos view (not in any Album or Event), then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Backspace ←</kbd>  or right click & Delete (1) Photo

[image]

This will move it to Recently Deleted.

To purge it from there, Edit menu >Show Recently Deleted, select it & Delete, or Delete All.